# Why the error 1616 while importing database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to import this data file as shown in the picture attached. I tried it using import in phpadmin, first the size very big error then I edited those two variables in php.ini,`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size both to 128M` Well then I even changed my.ini `myisam_sort_buffer_size` variable from `8M to 128M`, my file size is just `67M`. But still this error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ZQs.png)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160168/mysql-insert-delayed-deprecated-what-now

or remove this delayed word from mysql file.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: I guess you should add the same as an answer. I can then accept it.